# How to connect to Sybase via PHP

Tags: php, sybase, dbo

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase database with PHP5.  I believe I've successfully compiled PHP with `PDO_DBLIB`, as `phpinfo()` lists `dblib` under PDO drivers, and `freetds` as the `pdo_dblib` flavour.

However, when I try to test a connection, I get an error reading:

> 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

I'm trying to connect to a server on my LAN with this code:

```
$dbh = new PDO("sybase:host=192.168.1.xxx;dbname=[database-name]", '[user]', '[pass]');
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you don't have driver installed and enabled in php.ini
You can try this experimental driver:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having trouble connecting to the sybase server myself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `dblib` instead of `sybase`, like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=192.168.1.xxx;dbname=[database-name]", '[user]', '[pass]');
```

Answer (score -1):

PDO wouldn't work, or at least there is no PDO Sybase support for php. On Windows, you can use ODBC, and [PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) or [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php), it might sound weird, but it should work.

Second option and I would recommend it, is to connect directly to Sybase (SqlAnywhere), but you need to install [SQL Anywhere PHP Module](http://www.sybase.co.uk/detail?id=1019698)

Comment: Zdenek Machek, thanks for the link to the SQL Anywhere PHP Module.

Comment: I'm trying to use the SQL Anywhere PHP Module, but when I start httpd, I get this error: "The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure that libdbcapi_r.so can be found in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable."

I've added "SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64" to my httpd.conf file.  However, phpinfo still shows the Apache Environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH as /usr/local/apache2/lib.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, on your machine needs to be installed Sybase SqlAnywhere or at least SqlAnywhere client and this library needs to be added to system path, see "echo $PATH"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've installed SQL Anywhere 12 Web edition, and libdbcapi_r.so is sitting in /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64.  I've added `"/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64"` to my system path (it shows when I "echo $PATH".)  However, I still get the same error from sqlanywhere.  

I understand that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is different from the system path, but I cannot find a way to change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH listed under Apache Environment phpinfo().  The /opt/sqlanywhere12/bin64/sa_config.sh script doesn't seem to affect Apache.  Is this variable indeed what I need to change?
Many Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use the SQL Anywhere PHP Module with PHP5 and It seems that is not possible. I got an error that the module and php are compiled with different module API

Comment: Then only solution is to compile extension from source code. Try Vagrant, these sort of things is sometimes better to test in virtual machine.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  PDO_DBLIB specifically states it is for connecting to Sybase: *PDO_DBLIB is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases through the FreeTDS library.*

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ubuntu you can put the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** inside envvars and it seems to read... still trying to find a way to get it to stick on **RHEL** based systems... Windows I am not too sure about I would hope you could set a system wide variable under

> my computer -> properties -> advanced options

If are using **RHEL** based systems it might be better to include the: 
**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/** in the httpd restart script (check to see if it loads **/etc/sysconfig/httpd** and if so add the line in there - now restart apache and you should see some activity.

Comment: This isn't even relevant to the question being asked.